# Change active on click in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i have list of items coming from (data).I would like to change my class to active by on click event, but by default I want my first item to be active by and on-click I want to change it further.

I have tried this much. I'm able to change it to active class, by im stuck to keep the first item as active and change it further.

```
  intentFunct(data) {
    this.setState({ active: data, intentId: data.id });
  }

  handleList(data) {
    return (
      <ul class="list-group-item">
        <li
          className={this.state.active === data ? "list-group-item active" : ""}
          id={data.id}
          onClick={() => this.intentFunct(data)}
        >
          {data.intentName}
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
```

my expected result is, I want my first item in the list to have active class and then change when I click other items.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are updating a global state and not a state by object.
But anyway you don't have to use state in this case you can just change the class.

Comment: @Baldráni,my list is coming dynamically,how can i directly change the class, can u explain me how?

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are trying to achieve is something in the lines of:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export class List extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      { id: 222, intentName: "data 222" },
      { id: 333, intentName: "data 333" }
    ],
    activeIndex: 0
  };

  intentFunct = idx => {
    this.setState({ activeIndex: idx });
  };

  handleList(data) {
    const { activeIndex } = this.state;

    return (
      <ul class="list-group-item">
        {data && Array.isArray(data) && data.map((d, idx) => (
          <li
            className={activeIndex === idx ? "list-group-item active" : ""}
            id={d.id}
            // Note that using arrow functions inside "onClick" is an anti-pattern
            onClick={() => this.intentFunct(idx)}
          >
            {d.intentName}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return <div>{this.handleList(data)}</div>;
  }
}
```

You can also check how it works at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflowchange-active-on-click-in-reactjs-nsefi).

The basic idea is that you have to setup an `activeIndex` that is initially set to `0`, your "first item"

You then render the list iterating over it with `map` and check if the `index` of the mapped value is the same as your current `activeIndex`, if it is the same, then you mark it as active, as seen in `activeIndex === idx ? "list-group-item active" : ""`

Now when the user **clicks** one of the items you have to pass the item's **index** to the `intentFunct`, which will set the `activeIndex` to the given index, and then the clicked item will become **active**

Comment: i tried ur code, but i got an error : Parsing error: Identifier 'data' has already been declared (for the line :const { data, activeIndex } = this.state;)

Comment: Which error did you get? I guess it would require some changes for it to work properly on your code. But if you need you can check the codesandbox link I provided above with everything working. https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflowchange-active-on-click-in-reactjs-nsefi

Comment: Ah I see the error, you are declaring data somewhere already. Can you copy your code here or in a fiddle? Or update your question to have your entire component?

Comment: and also i have written this outside of my render not inside render function.

Comment: check the updated answer. I added your `handleList` function.

Comment: i got another saying data.map() is not a function.

Comment: Added a check in my response so we only try to map if data exists and is an array. `data && Array.isArray(data) && data.map...`

Comment: can we connect somewhere in person so that i can show you my complete code. bit important for my tomorrow's project.

Comment: or any other way to contact you in person? @JCQuintas

Comment: If nothing is rendering, then you probably need to fetch the data to use there. You can always edit your original question in order to add more details. Would probably be wise to display the full component we are talking about.

Comment: i have put my full code in the condesand box. can you please review it(nlp.js)?

Comment: I need the url for it. :)
When you change something in mine it creates a new one just for you.

Comment: that is the same url as mine, you probably have to save it (ctrl + s) and share the new url generated.

Comment: did u get it? hope u r able to understand it.!

Comment: I got it, but it looks like everything should be working. Only thing that I can think of is that your API request is not returning any value.

Comment: i used to get the list before, after adding ur code im not getting the list,what can be done now?